# Objects not getting passed into localstorage - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to make a web application where it fetches data from backend API and displays it into frontend (This works) and also having add to cart functionality. I'm trying to store the requested item into localstorage and using state too, When the user clicks on add to cart it should store the item or objects in their localstorage. When I click add to cart this gets added `cartItems [object Object]`(This is not clickable) which is not what I want. I want to store the actual objects in localstorage.

```
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import axios from 'axios'


function HomeScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
    function handleClick(id) {
        const chosen_product = axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${id}`)
        setCart(cart + {chosen_product})
        localStorage.setItem("cartItems", cart)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getProducts() {
            try {
              const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products/');
              setProducts(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
          }
       getProducts()
    },[])
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded" key={product.id}>
            <Card.Img src={'http://localhost:8000' + product.image} />
            <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title as="div">
                <strong>{product.name}</strong>
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text as="div">
            
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Text as="h3">
            ${product.price}
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Link>
                <Button onClick={()=>handleClick(product.id)} className="btn-primary">Add to cart</Button>
            </Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store things in localStorage as a string. You also need to wait for the API response, `axios.get` returns a Promise.

```
async function handleClick(id) {
  try {
    const chosen_product = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${id}`)
    setCart(cart + {chosen_product}) // This is wrong, can't add array to object
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cart)) // This is wrong, cart will still be the previous value
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

In fact you already have this code structure in getProducts...

Also this code makes no sense:

```
setCart(cart + {chosen_product})
```

You can't add an object to an array.

Also setting `cart` straight after `setCart` won't work and `cart` will still be your previous value at that point, simplest solution is to create a variable for your new state.

```
const newCart = cart.concat(chosen_product);
setCart(newCart);
localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(newCart));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the object into a JSON string like so:

```
localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cart))
```

And you can then get the item and parse it like this:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
```

And you are back to a Javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify the object because

```js
localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cart))
```

and you can parse the item to js object again using JSON.parse

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the object value after stringifying it.

> storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);

**keyName**
A DOMString containing the name of the key you want to create/update.

**keyValue**
A DOMString containing the value you want to give the key you are creating/updating.

Storing:

```
localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cart))
```

Retrieving:

```
const val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
```