# Objects not getting stored into localstorage. - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to make a web application which fetches products from backend API and displays it and I'm also trying to implement add to cart functionality which works by storing products added to the cart by the user in their local storage When I click add to cart this is what gets added currently `cartItems [{}]` which is not what I want. I want to store the actual object of the product. Here is my current code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import axios from 'axios'


function HomeScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
    const [newCart, addToCart] = useState([])
    async function handleClick(id) {
        const chosen_product = axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${id}`)
        const newCart = cart.concat(chosen_product);
        setCart(newCart);
        localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(newCart));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getProducts() {
            try {
              const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products/');
              setProducts(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
          }
       getProducts()
    },[])
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded" key={product.id}>
            <Card.Img src={'http://localhost:8000' + product.image} />
            <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title as="div">
                <strong>{product.name}</strong>
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text as="div">
            
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Text as="h3">
            ${product.price}
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Link>
                <Button onClick={()=>handleClick(product.id)} className="btn-primary">Add to cart</Button>
            </Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: You asked the [same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734827/objects-not-getting-passed-into-localstorage-react-js)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry but the solutions in that question did not work for me so I asked again.

Comment: You received [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66734918/1280867) that covered the axios misuse.

Comment: That did not solve the issue for some reason and I'm sorry If i offended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objects not getting passed into localstorage - React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734827/objects-not-getting-passed-into-localstorage-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

axios.get returns a promise that needs to be resolved via await/then,catch

updated handleClick function:-

```
    async function handleClick(id) {
     try{
        const chosen_product = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${id}`)
        const newCart = cart.concat(chosen_product);
        setCart(newCart);
        localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(newCart));
     }
     catch(error){
      // error-handling goes here
     }
   }
```